# Reactive architecture for OpenLayers

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, ngrx, reactive

I would like to add OpenLayers (OL) with custom vector graphics to my current project which is based on Angular, NgRx.

After I went through few examples and API documentation I can see that this library was not intended to be very much reactive.

What should be the best approach here?

I was thinking about storing created map inside NgRx store and updating view based on actions. Like also managing different layers in store and instead firing HTTP request in VectorSource loader just fire action and handle it by effect?

I'm trying to figure out some architecture that could be readable also in a few years later and I'm not sure if I understand the OL correctly or if I miss something.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/quentin-ol/ngx-openlayers ? It would probably be useful but unfortunately it's pretty much dead. You can bind items in your store to open layers in your template using the components the library provides.